# Migration to Cloud Endpoints v2

Tags: java, ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have a few Google App Engine standard Java environment applications that are backends for mobile apps, there are both Android and iOS clients.

Some time ago I received an email that the Cloud Endpoints v1 will be no longer supported and that I need to migrate to the new version v2.

**What happens to the already existing (and using endpoints v1) mobile clients when I upgrade the version of the server?**

My Android clients use maven-generated libs and the integration with iOS is based on discovery docs generated by another maven command.

I'm afraid that after the upgrade the clients will not be able to communicate with my backend anymore (as long as they do not update their libs / docs). As we cannot make the app-users upgrade their apps, I hope that the server changes will not affect all the clients that are already running on production.

Answer (score 0):

No. It will not affect anything. The old version would not be supported after 2, August 2018. The new version has few benefits as given in the documentation.

- Reduced request latency
- Better integration with App Engine features (such as custom domains)
- Official support for Guice configurations
- Optionally, new API management features

Please follow the instructions given [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating). I have shifted to the new version just a few days ago and everything is working as usual.